# Testing MySQL database on LAN client

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, lan

I am attempting to create a MySQL DB and Java client app for my home network. I haven't really had any experience with MySQL other than PHPMyAdmin for a website backend (also have used SQLite). I have downloaded the full MySQL installation and a test DB from the MySQL website. On the server machine I successfully connected to the DB as root. Not a difficult task.

Now I want to connect to the DB from my client PC, just to check I can. Eventually I will use the JDBC driver to connect from my Java client app, but before that I just want to check I can connect.

How should I do this? SHould I just install the MySQL command line program onto the client PC?

EXTRA INFO: forgot to add, I'm using Windows 7 on all my machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could install the MySQL to get MySQL command line program and connect with it, but also you can use another MySQL client tool like PHPMyAdmin, [dbForge Studio for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/) or another one.

To connect from remote host you should create special accout for it, e.g. - 'user_name'@'your_host_name'. Find more information here -

[Specifying Account Names](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/account-names.html)

[Account Names and Passwords](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html#grant-accounts-passwords)